# How to read multiple objects variable python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pytorch

I had saved a file as an csv. File contents:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ({'abcd': [1,0,10,100,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0], 'defgh' : [1,1,0,00,10,100,101,1,1,1,0,0,0]}, 0.123, ["ABCD", ""], "www.abc.com") |

Object in Column2 comprises of  variables:

1. Dictionary
2. Number
3. Array of string
4. string

The columns value was created as:\

```
df["column1"] = 0
df["column2"] = dict, num, arr, str
df.to_csv('abc.csv')
```

I want to read the value of column 2 and divide into 4 variables

1. Dictionary
2. Number
3. Array of string
4. string
   What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: There is so much unclear here, but one is clear - this is wrong format to use to store data in the file. Clear XY problem.

Comment: The data has already been created using the logic I shared. I am just trying to use the data and utilize it

Answer (score 1):

This is a terrible idea to store those data, converting to CSV will make everything a string.

You can recover the original format with `ast.literal_eval`:

```
from ast import literal_eval
df['Columns2'] = df['Columns2'].apply(literal_eval)
```